# change the image name in php

Tags: php

hi i want to upload image on server and i have done it but the problem is when i upload image with the same name it give me error what i want to do to append something to end of image name so that every image has its own unique 
name.

```
$TARGET_PATH =$TARGET_PATH . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
if (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))
{
    // here will be the appended term
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
$TARGET_PATH =$TARGET_PATH . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
while (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))
{
    $TARGET_PATH =$TARGET_PATH . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name'],'.jpg') . uniqid() . '.jpg';
}
```

That way it will always produce a unique file name. note this will work for files with the extension jpg. should you want to use it for other files then i would recommend this:

```
  $TARGET_PATH =$TARGET_PATH . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    while (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))
    {
        $TARGET_PATH =$TARGET_PATH . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name'],'.' .$ext) . uniqid() . '.'.$ext;
    }
```

supplying an extension to basename will remove the extension from the name. 
Adding uniqid() will add some unique entropy to the end of the filename. If that's to long for you, you could replace it with rand(0,10);

This method also has the advantage of only executing when it finds that the file does exist, otherwise it won't run at all.

Comment: thanks for reply but could you please explain the use of uniqid() and rand(0,10); the rand method just take the within the limit of 0 and 10...?

Comment: Well it just depends on how long you want your filenames. Uniqid() produces a unique identifier and will be quite long. Rand(0,10) will produce a number between 0 and 10. Between the two methods, uniqid has a much higher probability of the file not existing. rand(0,10) could potentially crash your application with a stack overflow because the loop would never end if there are already 10 files with the exact same name. It really comes down to how you suspect your application will be used. You may also wish to replace it with the "time()" function instead.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't get error when a file already exist with the same name.
I think your problem should be something else.

but if changing the name just solve your problem also you can use timestamp and adding it to your file name to be unique.

```
function uniqueName($filename){
    $f = explode('.', $filename);
    $ext = $f[count($f)-1];
    return implode('.', $f).time().'.'.$ext;
}
```

this function will work for all extensions.

Comment: also, this way you won't need the conditional either. just append the time to any image you upload.

Comment: also you don't need to save upload time of files in your db.

Answer (score 0):

Think about a function which returns a unique name - like (untested and is very improvable):

```
<?php
// ...
function getUniqueFilename($targetPath = '.', $extension = 'jpg') {
  $uniqueFilename = sha1(time() . mt_rand(1, 150)) . '.'. $extension;

  if(file_exists($targetPath . $uniqueFilename)) {
    getUniqueFilename($targetPath, $extension);
  } else {
    return $uniqueFilename;
  }
}

// and you call it like
$newFilename = getUniqueFilename('.', 'gif');
?>
```

just as an idea ;-)

Comment: Yes however, this seems fairly cpu intensive for such a simple task don't you think?

Comment: I don't think so... Normally it just generates a random filename, checks if the file exists and return the filename in the most of the cases because the file is not existant. BUT - you may be right. I didn't test it.